# Why is the Spectrum of an Operator Used as the Domain in Continuous Functional Calculus?

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory, functional-calculus

I'm currently working to grasp the concepts of (continuous) functional calculus, aiming to prove the spectral theorem for bounded self-adjoint operators as outlined in *"Introduction to Hilbert space and the theory of spectral multiplicity"* by Paul Halmos and *"Quantum Theory for Mathematicians"* by Brian Hall. The specific definition of continuous functional calculus I'm exploring is as follows:

**Theorem 8.3** (*"Quantum Theory for Mathematicians"* - Brian Hall):
Let $A \in \mathcal{B}(H)$ be a self-adjoint operator. Then there exists a unique bounded linear map from $\mathcal{C}(\sigma(A); \mathbb{R})$ to $\mathcal{B}(H)$, denoted as $f \mapsto f(A)$, such that when $f(\lambda)=\lambda^{m}$, we have $f(A)=A^{m}$. This mapping, denoted as $f \mapsto f(A)$, where $f\in \mathcal{C}(\sigma(A);\mathbb{R})$, is commonly referred to as the (real-valued) functional calculus for the operator $A$."

My questions are mainly concerned with the choice of domain of $f$:

1. Why is the domain of $f$ restricted to $\sigma(A)$ (the spectrum of $A$)? Why not simply use $\mathbb{R}$ as the domain, given that $A$ is self-adjoint and $\sigma(A) \subset \mathbb{R}$?
2. In Halmos' book, for a polynomial $p(\lambda)=\sum_{j=0}^{n}\alpha_{j}\lambda^{j}$ and an operator $A$ on a Hilbert space, he defines $p(A)$ to be $p(A)= \sum_{j=0}^{n}\alpha_{j} A^{j}$. To me, this seems acceptable, assuming that the domain and codomain of $p(A)$ and $A$ are the same. However, am I correct that when considering more complex functions like Borel or holomorphic functions, we need to be cautious about our choice of domain? Unfortunately, this aspect is not generally explained.

**Update**:
The proof makes use of the Stone-Weierstrass theorem, i.e. that polynomials are dense in $C(K;\mathbb{R})$, where $K$ is a compact set. Thus we could use any compact $K \supset \sigma(A)$. However, since $\sigma(A)$ is compact, we wouldn't gain anything as pointed out in the answers below.

Comment: There is a natural extension of the continuous functional calculus  to the Frechet Space   $ C(\mathbb C)$ of all continuous functions $f \colon \mathbb C \to \mathbb C$
$$ C(\mathbb C)\ni f \mapsto f(A) \in \mathcal B(H).$$   This extension satisfies $\|f(T)\| = \|f\|_{C(\sigma(A))}$ and is continuous  in the sense that if $A_n \to A$ in $\mathcal B(H)$ then $f(A_n) \to f(A)$ in $\mathcal B(H)$ for every $f \in C(\mathbb C)$.

Comment: Do you have a reference where I can read more?

Comment: The extension is the $*$-homomorphism $C(\mathbb C) \to C(σ(A)) \to \mathcal B(H)$. To establish continuity, show first that if  $p \in C(\mathbb C)$ is a polynomial. To show that it holds for arbitrary $f \in \mathbb C$, let $ε>0$. Find a compact set $K$ containing the spectrums of $A_n,A$ and find polynomial $p$ such that  $\|f-p\|_{C(K)}<ε/2$

Comment: (cont.)  and estimate  \begin{align*}
                    \|f(A_n) - f(A) \| &\le \|f(A_n) - p (A_n) \| + \| p(A_n) - p(A)\| + \|p(A) - f(A) \|
                    \\
                    & = \|f-p\|_{C(σ(A_n))} + \|p(A_n) - p(A) \| + \|f-p\|_{C(σ(A))} 
                    \\
                    &\le  2 \|f-p\|_{C(K)} +  \|p(A_n) - p(A) \| 
                    \\
                    &  < \epsilon +  \|p(A_n) - p(A) \| 
                \end{align*}
hence $\limsup_n  \|f(A_n) - f(A) \| \le \epsilon$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The point is that $f(A)$ is determined by the properties/behaviour of $f$ on $\sigma(A)$. In particular, $f$ does not even need to be defined for $\mathbb R\setminus\sigma(A)$.

This becomes more clear when we consider the case in which $H$ is finite-dimensional: For a symmetric matrix $A$, which has a diagonalization of the form $Q^\top A Q = \operatorname{diag}(\lambda_1, \ldots)$, you would define said map $f$ according to
$$f(A):= Q\operatorname{diag}(f(\lambda_1), f(\lambda_2), \ldots)Q^\top.$$
Note that $f|_{\{\lambda_1, \ldots\}}$ (i.e. $f$ on $\sigma(A)$) is all that you need to know about $f$ in order to define $f(A)$.

*Comment for question 2.* The definition is consistent for polynomial $f$, but extends to more general functions as long as they are defined of $\sigma(A)$.
Note that the theorem states that if there is a function $f$ defined on $\sigma(A)$, you *may define (!) $f(A)$* accordingly, in a way that is consistent with the case in which $f$ is a polynomial. The fact that $f(A)$ is a definition cannot be stressed enough.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with "$f$ does not even need to be defined for $\mathbb{R} \setminus \sigma(A)$". Clearly $C(\sigma(A);\mathbb{R}) \neq C(\mathbb{R};\mathbb{R})$ and therefore by choosing $\mathbb{R}$ as domain we would get a different functional calculus. But $f$ would be defined.

Comment: It only matters what $f$ looks like on $\sigma(A)$. You could pick $f\in C(\mathbb R)$, then in the above Theorem, you would have to use its restriction $f_\sigma:=f|_{\sigma(A)}\in C(\sigma(A))$ (to be very rigorous). The restriction from $f$ to $f_\sigma$ is nothing else than saying: We pick $f$, but we only care how it behaves on $\sigma(A)$. Of course $f$ and $f_\sigma$ are not the same functions, but often it is more convenient to define $f$. For example, you might say $f(\lambda) = \lambda^2 + 2\lambda$, but all that matters in the Theorem is the behaviour of $f$ on $\sigma(A)$.

Comment: But of course, all that is needed is $f$ on $\sigma(A)$ - if $f$ would extend beyond that, that would be fine, but does not matter for our purpose.

Comment: The spectral measure version of the spectral theorem is $A=\int_{\sigma(A)}\lambda \mathrm{d}E_{\lambda}$ with $E_{\lambda}$ being a spectral measure. Since the integral is over $\sigma(A)$ I see what you mean with "It only matters what $f$ looks like on $\sigma(A)$". I think my confusion arises from the fact  that $\sigma(A)$ as domain seems arbitrary as long as we haven't proved the spectral theorem.

Answer (score 4):

1. The proof of the theorem has $C(\sigma(A);\Bbb{R})$ mapping one-to-one onto the self-adjoints of the norm-closed subalgebra generated by $A$.  Consequently, $C(\sigma(A); \Bbb{C})$ maps one-to-one onto the norm-closed subalgebra generated by $A$.  You can extend the mapping artificially to any superset of $\sigma(A)$ by mapping $f$ to the same operator as $f\rvert_{\sigma(A)}$ maps to.  If you do this you get a kernel of all functions $f$ that are zero on $\sigma(A)$.
2. Since $A$ is bounded, the domain is always the entire Hilbert space $H$.  The codomain is a subspace of $H$ so you can take powers like that.  The largest class to which the functional calculus extends is bounded Borel-measureable functions on $\sigma(A)$.  The image is the von-Neumann algebra generated by $A$.  If you want to apply the calculus to a holomorphic function defined on an open neighborhood of $\sigma(A)$ that's fine, because $\sigma(A)$ is compact so the function is still bounded on $\sigma(A)$.

Answer (score 2):

To complement the other answers, if you decide to use $C(\mathbb R)$ instead of $C(\sigma(A))$, you are unnecessarily disallowing valid functions. For an example consider $$A=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&2\end{bmatrix}$$ and the function $f(t)=1/t$.